# Error con foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

El problema que tengo es que el foreach en un controlador (para crear un pdf) y no me funciona

```
 $datos_integrantes = S_Solicitud_Integrante_Persona::where('id_solicitud', '=', $datos->id_solicitud)->get();

escribir($datos, $datos_integrantes));

  public function escribir($datos, $integrante)
    {
        
        return " <section style='margin-top: 10px;'>
        <div align='left'>
            <table width='100%'>
               @foreach ($integrante as $integrante)
                        <tr>
                            <td> ".$integrante->apellido." ".$integrante->nombre." </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach 
         </table> </div> </section>"; }
```

El error que me tira es: Property [apellido] does not exist on this collection instance. Ahora bien, si utilizo otra variable:

```
                            @foreach ($integrante as $inte)
                        <tr>
                            <td> ".$inte->apellido." ".$inte->nombre." </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

Dice Undefined variable: inte.
Intente hacerlo manualmente, sin usar bucle, y anda:

```
.$integrante[0]->apellido." ".$integrante[0]->nombre."
.$integrante[1]->apellido." ".$integrante[1]->nombre."
```

Pero necesito el bucle, y no entiendo por qué el foreach no funciona, nunca me habia pasado! Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes retornar la plantilla como un string desde el controlador. Debes crear un archivo de plantillas `.blade.php` con ese contenido y pasarle solo `$integrante` como parámetro para que blade pueda interpretar el `@foreach` durante la compilación.

Ejemplo:

```php
// plantilla.blade.php
<section style='margin-top: 10px;'>
    <div align='left'>
        <table width='100%'>
        @foreach ($integrante as $inte)
            <tr>
                <td> {{ $inte->apellido }} {{ $inte->nombre }} </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach 
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

```php
// Controlador
return view('ruta/plantilla', ['integrante' => $integrante]);
```

o también

```php
// Controlador
return view('ruta/plantilla', compact('integrante'));
```

Como lo tienes actualmente, lo único que estás haciendo es retornar un string que busca concatenar el arreglo `integrante` como si fuese un string (ya ahí tienes un error), y luego concatenas además la propiedad `apellido` de la variable `$int` que no está declarada. No se está ejecutando ningún foreach.